# jquery .click-event does not use counter variable like expected

Tags: jquery, variables, for-loop, click, counter

I have something like a beginner problem, because javascript uses the variable 'i' in an unexpected way:

```
for(var i=0; i<3;i++){
    $("a[href=#markers"+i+"]").click(function() {
        console.info(this);
        console.info("click: "+i);
    });
}
```

Here is my console:

```
<a href="#markers0">
click: 3
<a href="#markers1">
click: 3
<a href="#markers1">
click: 3
```

But I want this:

```
<a href="#markers0">
click: 0
<a href="#markers1">
click: 1
<a href="#markers1">
click: 2
```

Can someone help and resolve this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop will continue to increase the `i` variable independent of whatever you click.

Why not just target all elements that has a href starting with `#markers`, and then get the number from the href, like so:

```
$('a[href^="#markers"]').on('click', function() {
     var i = $(this).attr('href').replace('#markers','');
     console.log("click: "+i);
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cUVUq/1/)

Or if for some strange reason you need the loop, you can always just store the variable in data() :

```
for(var i=0; i<3;i++){
    $("a[href=#markers"+i+"]").data('i',i).click(function() {
        console.info(this);
        console.info("click: "+$(this).data('i'));
    });
}​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cUVUq/2/)

Comment: Yhea, cool, the data() solution is what I needed!
I have circa 40 <a> which beginns with "href=#marker" and I don't wanted to use some crazy string-operations, which slows the things down ;)
thank you!

Comment: It is of course a closure problem, and I wrote that in my answer to begin with, and started messing around with the usual way of solving closures, an extra function, but edited it out as jQuery objects can store data all on their own with data(), and it just seems so much simpler. A function would probably be a little bit faster, but have'nt really tested it ?

Comment: I'll take that back? In my browser at least, `data()` seems to be faster than a function!  http://jsperf.com/closure-vs-data --

Comment: thats sounds interesting; I think I will use `data()`, because it is also faster in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with the help of closures.. In your case the **click event** is being just assigned with the **variable i** .. But by the time you click the link the value of i is set to 3 as all point to the same memory location..

Using closures solve the problem here as the function is executed for the current value of i..
Try this

```
for(var i=0; i<3;i++){
  (function(num){
       return  $("a[href=#markers"+num+"]").click(function() {
                  console.info(this);
                  console.info("click: "+num);
               });
   })(i)
}
```

[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/cUVUq/4/)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I now asking my self which solution is better in my case when I have circa 40 (or even more) `<a href="#markers">` ... closures or data()?
Closures seems to be the more native way, but quite complicated ...

Comment: It seems to be complicated in the first glance but it is simple once you grasp the concept .. You are just encasing that in a function , passing the current variable and immediately executing it and then returning it back ..

Comment: that's interesting, but I don't understand: How does the variable `num` knows thaht it starts with `0` ?

Comment: similar to   function(num){} FUNCTION DECLARATION     ,... Then calling it  func(i)  .. But as it is an anonymous function here (function without a name) .. So you execute it immediately

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a separate on-click handler for each link, or to select each link separately.
Also the other answers only work with a predefined set of links (0..2).
My version uses a single selector, a single handler, and works with any number of links.
Even with holes between them.

```
// all of the #markers* href elements
var links = $("a[href^=#markers]");

// common click handler
links.click(function () {
    // get the number from the href
    var num = parseInt($(this).attr("href").substr(8), 10);    
    console.log("click", num);
});
```

Demonstrating fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/8z6CA/2/).